# Preparation for modeling in grad school

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I'm currently a first year grad student in an applied math program.  I really love modeling, but everything in my modeling course is flying way over my head.  Where can I look for a decent introduction to this subject?  We didn't offer the course in my undergrad school, so I'm kind of trying to learn on the fly.

Comment: For what we've done in class so far, there's been projects on heat models, fuel spread, and population models, so I really need to find something to help me understand these kinds of things, especially how to program them in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could search for simulation in chemical engineering and processing. This is the area in which I already spent 53 years as a modeller. Another area is applied thermodynamics (say, equations of state). If you enjoy applied math and programming, take anything in physics or chemistry. Take the equations, develop a program, use this program and ... enjoy. Good luck !

Comment: It's the develop a program part that I get stuck on.  I don't really know what I'm doing and my class assumes I have some background in the material already.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of stuff do you work on? "Modeling" is a very broad definition. You can try a "balls-into-bins" type of problems (http://www14.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/personen/raab/publ/balls.pdf), or analysis of algorithms (like this: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397501001827), which focuses on runtime.